Configure Linux to regularly sync cached data to disk
The sync command "writes any data buffered in memory out to disk". As far as I understand, data may be buffered in memory for very long time, even if the disks have no activity.
How can I properly configure Linux to automatically sync regularly?
The scenario is a storage server, where I would like to prevent cached data being prevented from being written to disks for too long, which leads to corrupted data in case of system crash or power loss.

There is a difference between corruption and loss. Corruption may happen on various levels (file system, data base, application) and can only be prevented by measures on each of these levels; for example, these days file systems are typically journaling so that crashes are less likely to corrupt them (i.e., leave them in a faulty and perhaps unusable state). Similar considerations may be apply to the database or application. They may all be able to roll back to a known good state. But that rollback will cause data loss which could not even be prevented by disabling caching altogether.


How can I properly configure Linux to automatically sync regularly?

It already does so by default. See the vm.dirty_* sysctls in the vm sysctl section.
dirty_expire_centisecs
======================

This tunable is used to define when dirty data is old enough to be eligible
for writeout by the kernel flusher threads.  It is expressed in 100'ths
of a second.  Data which has been dirty in-memory for longer than this
interval will be written out next time a flusher thread wakes up.

dirty_writeback_centisecs
=========================

The kernel flusher threads will periodically wake up and write `old` data
out to disk.  This tunable expresses the interval between those wakeups, in
100'ths of a second.

The default for the latter is 500 cs, so every 5 seconds it will write out data that is at least 3000 cs (30 seconds) old. That's probably ~35-40 seconds worth of data loss at maximum.
If accumulated writes are large enough to reach a certain limit (above dirty_ratio or dirty_bytes) the process is more immediate.

The scenario is a storage server, where I would like to prevent cached data being prevented from being written to disks for too long, which leads to corrupted data in case of system crash or power loss.

If power loss is the more likely scenario, get a small UPS; if system crash is the more likely scenario, you have a bigger problem.

Both scenarios are possible because neither power loss (including UPS running out) nor system crash can be 100% prevented. These are all for the unlikely aren't they :) But great to know data loss is limited in these scenarios. And thanks for the citation!

System crashes generally don't happen that often – I haven't had a Linux file server crash in probably a decade. The problem with UPS running out can be prevented by cleanly shutting down the server before the UPS runs out; NUT network-ups-tools supports monitoring many UPS types via USB or RS232 and triggering an automatic shutdown at low battery (or just a sync if you want, or a script that reduces the writeback interval even further during outages).

allowing your ups to shutdown a server sometimes does more harm than good. on the other hand, out of power means out of users, right?

This page has a bit more details on the topic.

As grawity’s answer explains, Linux does this automatically (and so does essentially every other OS). The sync command (and related system calls and library functions, like syncfs() or fsync()) just serve to explicitly override this, possibly for a specific subset of the filesystem.
However, the way it handles it is somewhat complicated, and involves a couple of different sysctl values:

vm.dirty_ratio/vm.dirty_bytes: These control how much dirty memory any single process can have before the kernel will start forcing writeback itself. dirty_ratio configures it as a percentage of available system RAM, while dirty_bytes configures it as an absolute number of bytes of memory. Only the last one of these two sysctls that was written to has an effect. The default is for vm.dirty_ratio to be set to 10, which means 10% of available system RAM.
vm.dirty_background_ratio/vm.dirty_background_bytes: These are exactly equivalent to vm.dirty_ratio and vm.dirty_bytes, but control the limits for the system as a whole. The default is for vm.dirty_background_ratio to be set to 20, which means 20% of available system RAM.
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs: This configures a time limit for how long any piece of data written can remain in memory before the kernel will start trying to write it out, in hundredths of a second. IOW, if the limits set by the above four sysctls are not met, the kernel will start writing out dirty memory once this amount of time has elapsed since that dirty memory was written to. The default is 30000, which corresponds to 30 seconds.
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs. This controls how frequently the kernel will attempt to write dirty memory out to disk, specified as hundredths of a second between attempts. The default is 5, corresponding to twenty times per second.

Note that ‘available system RAM’ is not the same as total installed RAM, it’s what the kernel sees after all the reservations from the firmware and devices are handled (and is usually just a bit more than what the free command reports as total memory).
If you’re thinking logically, you probably notice some issues with those default values, especially on modern systems. For a system with 32 GiB of RAM for example, the defaults mean that up to about 6 GiB of memory might be dirty before the kernel forces writeback, which is then likely to take quite a while. The usual recommendation, which some distros actually follow out of box, is to set vm.dirty_ratio to 1 and vm.dirty_background_ratio to 2, corresponding to 1% and 2% of available system RAM, which will usually significantly reduce the amount of data that may be lost.
If your storage server sees lots of small, infrequent writes but not much else, you may want to also reduce vm.dirty_expire_centisecs (though I would not reduce it below about 1000).
